# Twilio TwinML inside Node.js App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters, twilio

How to implement and then interpolate parameters from the Twilio library? The below page only shows Twiml code.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml

In this case the FromCountry parameter. I am wrecking my head for 5 hours now and I can't find the answer. This is my code:

```
const http = require('http');

const express = require('express');

const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;

const app = express();

app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  twiml.message(`Hi! It looks like your phone number was born in {FromCountry should go here}`);

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
  res.end(twiml.toString());
});

http.createServer(app).listen(1337, () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port 1337');
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow, I made a few edits to your question to remove the greetings and thanks. Both aren't necessary as Stackoverflow is a Q&A site for programming related questions, and answering questions is what we're here for!

Answer (score 3):

The things you're looking for are in ***`req.body`*** so you need:

```
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Then:

```
app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
    const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

    twiml.message('It looks like your phone number was born in ' + req.body.FromCountry);

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
    res.end(twiml.toString());
});
```

---

The `FromCountry` might not always be available according to the docs:
(https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#request-parameters)

> Twilio also attempts to look up geographic data based on the 'From' and 'To' phone numbers. Twilio sends the following parameters, if available:

```
FromCity        // The city of the sender
FromState       // The state or province of the sender.
FromZip         // The postal code of the called sender.
FromCountry     // The country of the called sender.
ToCity          // The city of the recipient.
ToState         // The state or province of the recipient.
ToZip           // The postal code of the recipient.
ToCountry       // The country of the recipient.
```

---

This blog (How to Receive an SMS in Node.js...) might also help: 
(https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/08/how-to-receive-an-sms-in-node-js-with-twilio-and-hyperdev.html)

> ***Note:*** @Alan suggested in comments the link to ***Express req.body***
>   (https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add these lines to your app -

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

Otherwise your application will not parse the parameters in the request. URL encoding is required to convert this data into a string. From there, you will be able to see the req.body, which will look something like this -

```
{ ToCountry: 'US',
  ToState: 'HI',
  SmsMessageSid: 'SM6d9aaa6e3f9dc2gjhasgd98sa9d963f',
  NumMedia: '0',
  ToCity: '',
  FromZip: '94105',
  SmsSid: 'SM6dva08hjhasashasgdj6ehjags82363f',
  FromState: 'CA',
  SmsStatus: 'received',
  FromCity: 'SAN FRANCISCO',
  Body: 'Make sure you add bodyParser',
  FromCountry: 'US',
  To: '+18081111111',
  ToZip: '',
  NumSegments: '1',
  MessageSid: 'SM6d999999sdhgjuasjdgasd63f',
  AccountSid: 'ACa131b11110nbasbdjkasghd45e0fd9',
  From: '+14159990000',
  ApiVersion: '2010-04-01' 
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

twilio says they send you parameters in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

therefore, use express to parse the encoded request and pick the attributes you need off of the body.

example: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#express-route-specific